# Can NSArrayController bounds to core data run fetch in background thread?

Tags: macos, core-data, cocoa-bindings

I made `NSArrayController` bound to core data, which has more than 100k rows to fetch, and set UseLazyFetching as TRUE. surely `NSTableView` is bound to NSArrayController. all are set programmatically like this:

```
@implementation MainWindowController {
    NSArrayController *_arrayController;
}

- (void)windowWillLoad
{
    _arrayController = [[NSArrayController alloc] init];
    [_arrayController setManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [_arrayController setEntityName:@"User"];
    [_arrayController setUsesLazyFetching:YES];
    [_arrayController setSelectsInsertedObjects:NO];
    [_arrayController setPreservesSelection:NO];
    [_arrayController fetchWithRequest:nil merge:NO error:NULL];
}

- (void)windowDidLoad
{
    [super windowDidLoad];

    [self.tableView bind:NSContentBinding 
                toObject:_arrayController 
             withKeyPath:@"arrangedObjects" 
                 options:nil];
}
```

and I've found that all fetch operations, triggered by lazy fetching option while scrolling, are running in main thread and this cause UI is blocked while fetching is running. the following is from instrument.

[image]

Is there any way to run fetching in background thread?
I've tried using managed object context inited with `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`, but it makes no difference. :(
Or is it bad to use cocoa binding & core data to handle a lot of rows in table view? I'm quite familiar with NSFetchedResultsController from iOS and looking for something operating like it in OS X.

Answer (score 0):

You’re in for a world of heck if you try to do BOTH lazy AND multi-threaded fetches...BUT! There’s a solution that might would work for you.

If your objects aren’t too big (less than 30K each on average) you can fit them all in memory. So, when you first load your tableView just fetch the first 100 (or 1000?) objects, then dispatch to a separate thread with its own sub-managedObjectContext and fetch ALL the rest, then just move those objects into the main managedObjectContext.

This is still work, but it seems do-able, to me.